# Sprite animation not animating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, sprite, createjs

I'm trying to get a sprite to animate and flip depending on which key I press (move left, move right).

Right now the sprite is appearing on screen, but the sprite isn't animating correctly...
Following the sprite sheet, frames 0-9 should be him walking left, and 10-19 should be him walking right.

I try to achieve that with:

```
spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    images: [imgMonsterARun],
    frames: {width: 64, height: 64, regX: 32, regY: 32},
    animations: { walk_left: [0, 9], walk_right: [10, 19]
    }
});
```

[image]

Also, he should flip around depending on which key I hit, left or right. I thought I was doing that with

```
if (key == left) {
bmpAnimation.gotoAndPlay("walk_left");
```

and

```
if (key == right) {
bmpAnimation.gotoAndPlay("walk_right");
```

But those just switch him around, but don't play remainder of animation frames.

[demo with code here](http://www.hittingtreeswithsticks.com/Chinese%20Adventure/Chinese%20Adventure.html)

Thanks

Comment: When you hit top and bottom key, the animation seems to work fine...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only updating the stage when you respond to key presses, which will just update the stage once.

Try throwing a stage.update() into the empty `tick` function in the main JS file. This ensures the stage is constantly redrawn, which redraws your animating sprite as it changes frames.

The stage needs to be redrawn any time content changes, and SpriteSheet/BitmapAnimation change the frame constantly over time.

Cheers!

Comment: I wasn't aware that BitmapAnimation changes the frame constantly over time. I only want the bitmap to animate when I press the move key... is it possible to control BitmapAnimation like that?

Comment: You will have to add a listener to the Ticker, and update the stage during this time.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what @Lanny already said: Whenever you have the left/right-key pressed you execute `bmpAnimation.gotoAndPlay("walk_XXX");` each cycle, this results in always going to the first frame of that animation each cycle.
Instead you should just start the animation once, when you press the left/right-key the first time and stop the animation when you release that key.